# Why was this question removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, historical-lock

The question was this one: [What is SOA in plain English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026523/what-is-soa-in-plain-english). Since I don't have 10k yet I can't access the question any more, or read the close notes.

I wrote an answer to this question which got some praise, which is also why I noticed that it was gone.

Why wasn't it just closed, moved to a wiki or moved to another SE-site? It has certainly helped more people than some of these questions, which still exist:

[What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)
[What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)
[What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

Comment: It was deleted because it was '[too broad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64381/need-too-broad-reason-to-close).'

Comment: @DavidThomas: no, it was **closed** as too broad. Community members then voted to delete it. It received the last delete vote 2 hours ago.

Comment: Wait, we delete questions for being too broad now instead of closing them? What... Personally, I found reading the cached page useful. If you don't, move on - its closed and it won't be getting much attention anyway. No reason to delete a question that at least has some educational use.

Comment: From my observation, many a thing which was possible in 3/4 years earlier in SO is not possible now.

Comment: Personally I think that the best comment Q should have been moved to meta... I've run across some hilarious errors/comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SOA post was never locked as historically significant (as the posts you linked to *are*).

Not being locked, the community could vote to delete it. 2 hours ago, the 10th delete vote was cast (popular but closed, highly scored posts [require up to 10 delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)):

> [image]

If you want to move it to an (external) wiki somewhere, I suggest you grab the [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2026523%2Fwhat-is-soa-in-plain-english&oq=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2026523%2Fwhat-is-soa-in-plain-english) or [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140416055046/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026523/what-is-soa-in-plain-english) copies under the CC license.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I guess I don't agree with `historical significance > Educational` that seem to be a rule here. My answer got a couple of up votes every month. Guess I'll be back when I have 10k to cast my undelete vote.

Comment: @Niklas: it only needs 3, you bringing attention to it has resulted in 2 undelete votes so far. Who knows, it may be back sooner than you think. If it does, flag it for moderator attention and request a historical lock.

Comment: Sounds good, and I'll try to remember to do that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Niklas: Why not just simply move it to somewhere else where it is more on topic? Perhaps SO could have a "historical posts" sub-site where these threads could be easily migrated.

Comment: @FinalContest: we can do more than that; I already linked to the cached content, we can extract the markdown too if needed.

Comment: @Niklas It's back now

Comment: *Why* was it deleted? Isn't it obvious that a lock is better?

Comment: It was deleted because any trusted user can vote to delete. Only moderators have the ability to lock a post. Not to mention lots of users favor deletion of old content that no longer fits our guidelines and care nothing for historical locks.

Comment: I didn't vote to delete it, but I would if I saw it. It didn't fit current standards, it wasn't very important (you can read about this on Wikipedia) - lets clean it up.

Comment: A question that gets more than 100 up votes should be protected. How is 10 close votes > 100 up votes?

Comment: @Mattt: Don't conflate popularity with suitability. And a historical lock means that the post now can no longer be edited either. It'll atrophy in place.